# chemfig: Error when using fine adjustment of bond

Tags: chemfig

I'm having some problems when using fine adjustment of bond `#(<dim1>,<dim2>)` inside a `definesubmol` code.
The output is correct, but return a error message:

[image]

```
line 7: Illegal parameter number in definition of \CF@@ring. ...t,-3.25pt)[::30,,,,line width=6pt]>[::-75]}
line 9: Illegal parameter number in definition of \CF@remain@molecule. \chemfig{!{ring}}
      : No file Molecule.aux.
      : Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    It's works:\par
    \chemfig{(-[::-165])-[:-15]-[::30]-[::-75](-[::75])<[::-135]-#(-1.75pt,-3.25pt)[::30,,,,line width=6pt]>[::-75]}\par
    \bigskip
    \definesubmol{ring}{(-[::-165])-[:-15]-[::30]-[::-75](-[::75])<[::-135]-#(-1.75pt,-3.25pt)[::30,,,,line width=6pt]>[::-75]}
    Is drawn but return a error:\par
    \chemfig{!{ring}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No such warnings here. I am using MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6668 (1.40.19) (MiKTeX 2.9.6745 64-bit). Package: chemfig 2018/04/05 v1.31. Btw. try to re-run it, if you still see the warning.

Comment: I have try re-run. The warnings still persist. I am using `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6839 (1.40.19) (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)` and `Package: chemfig 2019/02/23 v1.34`.

Comment: I don't get any warning or error with texlive. Which engine do you use?

Comment: Your chemfig version is outdated, can you update? Current one is `2019/05/21 v1.41`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error with `chemfig` v.1.34, which is the version you are using.

With the current version v1.41 the code compiles without problem, so the solution is very simple: update your TeX distribution to get up to date with the current `chemfig` version